# Springboot custom annotation working in UT, however not working when program running

Tags: java, spring-boot

Custom annotation is defined in **Common** project. Follow is the code.

Annotation

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrackTime {
}
```

Aspect class

```java
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class MethodLogAspect {
    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MethodLogAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.test.common.control.TrackTime)")
    public void TrackTime() {
    }

    @Around("TrackTime()")
    public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object obj = null;
        long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            obj = joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            logger.info("Request info:{},Execution time:[{}]", requestInfo.toString(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime + "ms");
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Then there is a Restful project which name is **Business**, this project is import **Common** project.
In the action class, add @Tractime annotation in each function.

Action

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class VehicleAction {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MethodLogAspect.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @TrackTime
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getBookById", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ProcessResult<Book> getBookById(@RequestBody String id) {
        try {
            return funSetvice.getBook(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Main class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Trying to run UT, the annotation is working, track time log can be printed normally. However, when I start the program, using Postman to do the query, there is no track time log. Does anybody have any idea about it?

Comment: On your `MethodLogAspect` class, switch `@Configuration` for `@Component`. Also annotate your App class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

Comment: @NicoVanBelle this is not working either, I have tried `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`,  non of them is working

Comment: Keep all changes I mentioned and change the annotation in App to the following: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.test")`

Comment: yeah, add `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.test")` works fine. Thanks a lot. According by my test, no need to switch `Configuration` to `@Component`, and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is no need as well. just add `sacanBasePackages` is OK